# Number of real numbers between 0 and 1 vs number of all integers

Tags: infinity, real-numbers

Let `a` be the number of real numbers between 0 and 1

Let `b` be the number of all integers.

Can I say `b=2a+1`, since for every real number `n` where `0<n<1`, I can take `n` and remove the `0.` in the beginning, making it an integer, and have a positive and negative of that integer? I will also have `0` in the integer set which cannot be reached through above method, hence the `+1`.

I think the logic is pretty sound, are there any mistakes in this argument?

Comment: This fails, since an integer cannot have infinite length. There are uncountably many real numbers between 0 and 1 and countably many integers.

Comment: Can you refer me to an article that says integer cannot have infinite length? I have never seen it.

Comment: Yes, your logic is pretty unsound. Both these numbers are infinite, and infinities are nothing like finite numbers. The infinity of the real numbers between $0$ and $1$ is much much much larger than that of the integers. Nothing that you can write as a simple equation like that.

Comment: If you search this site or Wikipedia for Cantor+diagonal you will find much discussion of this

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you elaborate. I can see both `a` and `b` are infinite, and there can be relations between different infinities, can you point out where the logic is unsound, and why are there more real numbers between 0 and 1 than integers.

Comment: Because the integers are only those numbers which can be written as a finite sum of $1$, and equivalently written by finitely many digits. Numbers like $\frac13$ don't have a finite decimal expansion to begin with, so removing the $0$ first will not turn to an integer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I get it now. If I remove the `0.` before an irrational number between 0 and 1, I will get infinity which is not an integer.